# Magento - Checkout get product overview

Tags: php, magento, checkout, product

For a new theme i need to create a new one-page-checkout-page, but now i'm struggling with the overview of products.

I can fetch items with this:

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');    
$cartHelper->getCart()->getItems()
```

The problem now when i put it in a foreach is that i can't get the image and other product-data such as name and stuff.

After a foreach the type is `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item` but i can't find the explanation of that class anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `$item->getProduct()` on each item to get the product it is made of.